# Fairly Simple Hangman in Python

Tags: python, beginner, hangman

This is my take on a simple hangman game, which is played from command prompt.

```
import random

wordlist = []

word =  random.choice(open("words.txt").readlines()) 
#word.txt is a list of words, in the same directory with the game file.

length  = len(word) 

mock_word = "_ " * length 
#The underscores presented to the player

mock_word =  mock_word.split() 
#making it a list, since strings can't be assigned

used_lets = []

lives = 7

while True:
    print " ".join(mock_word) #Needs space in join, so the underscores are separated.
    let = raw_input("Give a letter: ")

    if len(let) > 1: #User can only give one letter
        print "Only one!"

    elif (let not in word):
        if let not in used_lets:
            lives = lives - 1 
            if lives == 0:
                print "Sorry you lost, the word was:", word
                break
            print "Try again, you have only %r lives left!" % lives 
            used_lets.append(let)
            print "So far you have used:"
            print used_lets 

    else:
        for i in range(length):
            if let == word[i]:
                mock_word[i] = let

    if "".join(mock_word) == word: #Making it a string again
        print word + " You won!"
        break
```

If you want to test, just set word to something. That is how I tested the loop. 
I would appreciate criticisms of my coding technique, and perhaps the suggestion of an alternative of the while loop use, which feels wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! While your post is on-topic, you could make it stand out more: perhaps you could add some console output of you playing a sample game. And, you could include specifically what you would like in a review.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr: This is pretty good for a beginner. It’s robust to bad input and plays smoothly. To improve it, you could use functions to make it more reusable, and I’ve suggested a bunch of small ways to tidy up your Python. But a high level it works well.**

---

I’m just going to dive in, run the script, and see what happens. You didn’t provide a words.txt file, so I just used this small sample:

```
american
captain
dictionary
fish
hangman
letter
list
```

Comments:

- Overall, it seems pretty robust. I was unable to cause a traceback or exception by passing in dodgy input – kudos!

  (And yes, I passed in an emoji thumbs-up, and it handled it fine.)
- At the risk of getting [bludgeoned to death by Jeff Atwood](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105), I found a pluralisation bug:

  ```
  Try again, you have only 1 lives left!
  So far you have used:
  ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'i']
  ```

  Should be “lives”.
- The program treats uppercase and lowercase letters as distinct. That’s not what I expect when I play Hangman – at least whenever I’m played it, I’m just guessing letters, not their associated case as well.
- There are a few cases where the program just asks for the next letter, and doesn’t give a helpful message. When I guess a letter that I’ve already guessed (correct or not), it goes straight to prompting me for a new letter without explaining why.

  That’s more adding polish than fixing a bug – but it would be nice.
- I think a newline between guesses would make the output much easier to read. That’s a personal preference though, not a bug.

---

At a high-level, the problem with this code is that it isn’t very reusable. It’s good to break your code down into functions – that allows it to be reused within the same file, or across other files.

For example, this script only allows me to play a single game of Hangman. Having a `play_hangman()` function would allow you to keep playing Hangman until the player got bored. Here are some suggestions to get you started:

- `play_hangman(word, number_of_lives)`
- `get_random_word_from_file(file_path)` – letting me specify the file path means I could drop in another word list easily

I think the while loop is fine for this purpose.

Once you have some functions in the file, you should use the [`if __name__ == '__main__'` construction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163), which allows the same file to be used both as a module and a script. Like so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    play_hangman('pomegranate', number_of_lives=8)
```

The code inside that if block only runs if the script is run directly; if you access part of the file via an import statement, it doesn’t run. That means you can import from the file without having to play a game of Hangman first.

---

Finally, here are some minor line-by-line comments and/or nitpicks:

- You’re pretty good for [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compliance. One line is a bit long, and you need a bit of extra spacing around your comments, but otherwise fine.
- The `wordlist` variable is unused.
- When you choose the word, you open the `words.txt` file, but don't close it again. You could add an explicit close, but a better approach is to use the `with` keyword when opening files, like so:

  ```
  with open("words.txt") as wordsfile:
      word = random.choice(wordsfile.readlines())
  ```
- The `length` variable is only used twice (and I’m going to get rid of the second usage shortly), so I’d remove it and just use it directly.
- The way you’ve constructed the `mock_word` list is a little strange. You could go straight to it in one line:

  ```
  mock_word = ['_'] * len(word)
  ```

  Also note that the word “mock” has a [special meaning in programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object), so I’d suggest picking a different name for this variable – perhaps `player_guess`?
- Don’t be stingy with variable names – characters are cheap. Names like `used_lets` and `let` can become `used_letters` and `guessed_letter`. It makes your program easier to read.

Now I’m diving into the heart of the program: the while loop that processes the player guess.

- The first if branch is fine. However, you’re only checking that I don’t enter too many characters; you don’t check that I enter enough characters. This loop could be improved by checking for an incorrect number of characters, and printing a generic message:

  ```
  if len(letter) != 1:
      print("Please enter a single character.")
  ```
- In the elif branch, a common way to decrement a variable is to write `lives -= 1`. That’s a bit more compact.

  In the print statement telling me how many lives I have left, you’re using the `%r` token. That’s fairly generic – it just prints the string representation of whatever gets passed in. Since you know that the `lives` variable is an integer, I think it’s better to use the more explicit token `%d`. As I read the string, I know what sort of data will appear here.
- In the else branch, a more Pythonic approach than iterating over the indexes is to use `enumerate()`, which iterates over the index and the array element together. Like so:

  ```
  for i, letter in enumerate(word):
      if guessed_letter == letter:
          player_guess[i] = letter
  ```

Answer (score 1):

First off I feel cheated, there is no hanging man.

---

Your code is really good! It follows PEP8 pretty well. But you came here for a review.

First, `wordlist` is not used and `mock_word` is instantly overwritten too.
You can change most of this into a few small lines.

```
word =  random.choice(open("words.txt").readlines())
length = len(word)
mock_word = ("_ " * length).split()
used_letters = []
lives = 7
```

In-line comments are annoying to read.

```
print " ".join(mock_word) #Needs space in join, so the underscores are separated.

#Needs space in join, so the underscores are separated.
print " ".join(mock_word)
```

Which was easier to read? I vote the second one 100% of the time.

For the first `if`:

- You may want to use `continue` in the first if.
  It may make the code nicer to read.
- Lets say I enter ''.
  It will fail silently.
- Also `let` is a bad variable name,
  use `char` or something better.

And if you were to implement that:

```
if len(char) > 1:
    print "Only one!"
    continue
if not char:
    print "Enter a letter!"
    continue
```

In the second if:

- It's normally not good to have brackets around if statements.
- You should use operators such as `-=`, it will make code easier to read, write and change.
- You can merge most of your prints into one. And,
- Finally you should use `str.format`.

This would look like:

```
if char not in word:
    if char not in used_lets:
        lives -= 1
        used_letters.append(char)

        if lives == 0:
            print "Sorry you lost, the word was:", word
            break

        print(
            "Try again, you have only {} lives left!"
            "So far you have used: {}"
        ).format(lives, used_letters)
```

As you are using Python2 you should use `xrange` rather than `range`.
One makes a list, the other makes a generator.
In short, `xrange` is faster to loop through.
You could also try using `enumerate`.

```
for index, letter in enumerate(word):
    if char == letter:
        mock_word[index] = char
```

---

So overall there is nothing really that wrong with your code.

To further improve it I would put all the code, except `import random`, in a function.
And then make a loop to ask the player if they want to play again.
As I have never met a person who asks to play a game of hang man, and you only play it once.

Answer (score 1):

- Do not abbreviate. If you do, do it so that the reader understands abbreviation easily. `let` for `letter` is very wrong. First, `let` is a valid English word, with a clear meaning to programmers. Second, vowels convey practically no information. Even `ltr` would be better.
- You are accepting non-letters as a valid input; you also made the game case-sensitive. I am not sure it is intentional. See below.
- Input validation is logically coupled together with input reading. Make them into function:

  ```
  def get_letter():
      while True:
          letter = raw_input("Give a letter ")
          if len(letter) > 1:
              print "Only one!"
          else if letter not in string.ascii_letters:
              print "Letter I said!"
          else:
              return letter.tolower()
          # You can add as much validation here
          # without disturbing the main loop.
  ```
- By testing `letter not in word` and then adding letter to `mock_word`, you are doing the essentially same work twice. Blindly try to put a letter in, and count how many times you have done it:

  ```
      insert_count = 0
      for i,l in enumerate(word):
          if letter == l:
              mock_word[i] = l
              insert_count += 1
  ```

  If `insert_count` remains 0, you know the guess was wrong. Of course, this should also be factored out into a function.

  Also notice that the `for i in range` loop is almost always wrong. `enumerate` is more Pythonic.
- Instead of testing for `"".join(mock_word) == word` I recommend to keep track of remaining unknown letters:

  ```
          remaining -= insert_count
  ```
- Having the `remaining` counter you could change the loop structure from `while True` to `while lives > 0 and remaining > 0`.
- You should inform user if the used letter is repeated.